# Как скрыть метод класса Java?

Tags: java, android-studio

Собственно, как скрыть/сделать не доступными некоторые методы класса?
Например, перезаписанные public методы класса-родителя:

```
public class MyLayout extends FrameLayout {

    public MyLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    /**
     * КАК СДЕЛАТЬ ЭТОТ МЕТОД НЕДОСТУПНЫМ / ИЗМЕНИТЬ ВИДИМОСТЬ ???
     */
    @Override
    public void addView(View child) {
        super.addView(child);
    }
}
```

В C#, видел, делали что-то такое:

```
//Вот это
public override string ToString() {}

//Меняли на это
private new string ToString() {}
```

А как в java сделать подобное никак не найду. Причем в Android Studio в классах библиотек, вот например Context, есть скрытые методы, которые выглядят так:

```
/** @hide */
public boolean isAutofillCompatibilityEnabled() {
    return false;
}
```

И, соответственно, этот метод не видим, хоть и public.
Отсюда и вопросы: как это сделано и как сделать так же?

И что это вообще за теги в комментариях (@hide, {@link } и т.п.)? Если пишу так же - говорит неизвестный тег.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17035271/what-does-hide-mean-in-the-android-source-code

Answer (score 3):

В `Java` можно написать так:

```
public class Base {
    protected void method() { ... }
}

public class Derived extends Base {
    @Override
    public void method() { ... }
}
```

Сделать наоборот, то есть уменьшить видимость метода (`protected` -> `private`), не получиться.